# Show that $T$ is surjective if $\sigma(T) \subset \partial \mathbb{D}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a Banach space   and an operator  $T\in B(E)$. We assume that $T$ is an isometry
if $\sigma(T) \subset \partial \mathbb{D}$ such that $\partial \Bbb{D}= \{ \lambda \in \Bbb{C}:|\lambda|=1\}$. Show that $T$ is surjective.
My attempt: We assume that $T$ is not surjective, which implies that $T$ is not  bijective. Then $0\in \sigma (T)$, contradiction.

Comment: It is correct. You should write $\sigma(T)\subset \partial \mathbb D$. $\sigma(T)\in  \partial \mathbb D$ does not make sense.

Comment: yes i forgot. thank you